# Uri with %20 cause ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage to throw a null reference exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am passing a URL string which contains `%20` (Url encoded space character) to instantiate a new `Uri` object, which I use the Uri as a parameter for `ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage`.

However when I call the `Scale` method of the `UIImage` object, a null reference exception occurs. How can I resolve this issue?

```
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/path%20with%20/image.jpg");
var image = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage(uri, null);
var small = image.Scale(new SizeF(32,32));
```

Comment: Stupid question, but: have you tried passing it without the %20 and use a real space instead? I'd assume that Uri takes care of the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the api incorrectly.

The DefaultRequestImage is an asynchronous method and the return value is either an image, if the image exists on the local cache already or null if the image does not exist in the cache.

The return value is null because there is nothing in the cache yet.  You must provide a notification function (the second parameter in the call, in this case, you have chosen not to provide one by passing null)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there documentation about ImageLoader api I can read more about?